# Jenkins + Rspec + Capybara integration test fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, rspec, jenkins

I've configured my CI server with Jenkins in order to run my test after each push to Git. I have some integration tests and there is always one that fails. The output given is that capybara can't find the element but if I run the test in local it works.

I've research a bit and I found headless gem but it doesn't work. I also tried to set Capybara.default_wait_time = 5 but nothing.

Does anyone know what kind of configuration I should set in order to get my jenkins green?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

The failure to find may be element within the environment.  Using the 'save_and_open' method will show the exact state of the page that is trying to be rendered in the CI server environment.  You can add it to a test as simply as:

```
it 'should register successfully' do
  visit registration_page
  save_and_open_page
  fill_in 'username', :with => 'mrUser'
end
```

This assumes that you can view the page on the CI server or alternatively with the headless version the file should be saved so that you review later.

Comment: The problem is that I have a modal that is hidden and it takes a few seconds, so capybara is searching for the element while the modal is being hidden.

Comment: The error then indicates that it can't find the modal since it's only looking at the primary screen.  So can you force the modal to have visibility?  Or simply navigate the DOM of the modal ?

Comment: I actually forcing the modal to be hidden after I click a button. But this process take a few seconds.